# Mac Virtualization on Windows 7

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I've been a Mac developer in the past but because of a job switch I had to move to PC/Windows since the last year.

I already have all my OS X dvds, I have VirtualBox, I have a VMWare Workstation license (thanks for my job).

I finally got OS X Lion to run on VMWare but it has many bugs. Then I thought about those OS X custom build for non-Apple hardware (such as iATKOS) so I thought maybe it would run a bit more stable but no.

The problem is, for financial reason I can't afford a Mac right now but I will in a near future, it's just that I need to test some projects I had on Mac back in the day to see if they still works on later versions of OS X.

So my question is, is there any "best" way of running OS X from Windows 7? I don't really mind if it's a bit slow, I just don't want it to crash non-stop while I'm trying to debug something.

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Comment: As you're violating the EULA, these questions (or, any Hackintosh questions) are [off-topic for Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/q/1471/48078), sorry. You *will* always experience problems, I guess. It's quite cheap to get a used Mac Mini. If you just want to test if something runs and don't depend on performance, this is probably the way to go about it.

Comment: +1 for @slhck. OS X on non-Apple hardware or on virtual machines has always been a hassle, your best bet is to get an used Mac (specially since you claim that you don't mind if it's a bit slow).